# Factor Analysis (Exploratory ) – Need few clarifications

Tags: factor-analysis

I have encountered some challenges in analysing my results using Factor Analysis. I'd be grateful if you could give me some advice please.

I am using an existing theory to analyse individuals Personal Values on a construction project. More specifically, I am using Schwartz (1992) Values Survey. This is a link to Schwart'z paper, which gives a brief overview of the theory and instrument. However my questions are around some statistics issues.
http://scholarworks.gvsu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1116&context=orpc&sei-redir=1&referer=https%3A%2F%2Fscholar.google.co.uk%2Fscholar%3Fq%3DSchwartz%2B2012%2BValues%2Btheiry%26btnG%3D%26hl%3Den%26as_sdt%3D0%252C5#search=%22Schwartz%202012%20Values%20theiry%22

**About my results:**
I have about 180 data sets. Each data set or response consists of 56 value items (Variables)
Each respondent was asked to rate each question on the **sale of -1 to 7**. This is based on Schwartz Theory and I decided to keep it the same.

I need to analyse my data as a single project and also, to slice the results according to management levels (5 in total) and separately in accordance to Company names (2 in total) (as my project investigates values in a multi-organisation project).

For Extraction I am using Principal Components as the method.
For rotation I started with Oblique (Promax) and kept Kappa at 4. I realised that the default iterations for Convergence of 25 was not giving me the rotations. **For the entire sample I had to adjust this to 29.
My first question is: Is this OK?** My background reading suggests it is fine.

When I get my results (for the entire 180 sample), I found that Kaiser Value is .839 and sig. is .000. The df is 1540.

**I got 15 factors** – with 66.2% cumulative variance. I am concerned with the large number of the factors. **Do you think this number is OK?** I have 56 variables and getting 15 factors.

Using the Pattern Matrix Table (on SPSS) – I noted that there are some **cross loading taking place** between different factors/ components. These are greater than 0.3. Sometimes even two factors have values of around 0.5 or so. What do I do in this case? **Do I remove such variables all together to see how this affects the results**? My initial attempt showed there was little change and the number of factors remained the same.

Finally, when looking at the "Component Correlation Matrix" – **I found that a number of the figures are greater than ".32"**. I have read if this is the case, then I can not treat my results as oblique and therefore I should use an Orthogonal Rotation like Varimax. How can I best approach this please?

I have to say I learned that there is no right or wrong answer in such processes, but I need some practical advice that can help me take this a little forward.

If you have any other tips or any observations you made please share with me. I am more than happy to clarify anything further.

Many thanks

Comment: Quite the project.  You pose so many questions that your post is unfortunately a poor fit for this format.  I recommend you go to our site's Help...Tour and perhaps modify your post.  But it seems what your situation calls for most is a mentor or consultant rather than one-time advice.  MTFBWY ~

Comment: Thank's for your comments @rolando2. I have taken your advice and modified the post. I am not expecting a solution. I'd like some advice on the questions I have raised.